# What is the cache control policy of Outlook web addin?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are looking for the cache control policy of Outlook web addin.

Specifically, if our manifest remains the same, while we update the content of the html that the manifest URL points to, how long it takes for the change to take effect.

We did not find any related documents related on [Office dev center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins). We did some debug with our addin and checked the response headers of the addin html (referenced directly by the manifest), it has "cache-control: private". Does it mean they will never expire? And we have to update our manifest to roll out any addin update?

We are also looking for the best practice to rollout manifest changes (we will be running production service). We are wondering if Office Store will poll manifest changes from our endpoint on a certain schedule. It would be great if someone can point me to the related document. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We follow regular web caching policies [found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control). `cache-control: private` indicates that the response is intended for a single user and must not be stored by a shared cache. It does not control expiration.

Comment: Thank you. Also want to confirm that our third party developers have full control on the cache control here. Things like "max-age" will not be overridden at the Outlook side right?

Comment: You right, the client doesn't do anything with caching policies so it will not be overridden, in case that's not the behavior you see, do let us know.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am seeing in the test. Just want to confirm it.